# Grouping and SUM with LINQ (on conditions)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data set (cars):

```
Brand     DateSold    Amount  
Toyota    06/07/2015  18.5  
BMW       01/01/2016  25.15  
Mercedes  06/06/2016  20.75
```

and I want to group by year and return the sum of the amounts i.e.:

```
Year Amount  
2015 18.5   
2016 45.9
```

and output it into a listbox. I tried:

```
var AmountsByYear = cars
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.Date.Year })
                .Select(x => String.Format("{0}", new {Date = 
x.Key.Year, Amount = x.Sum(z => z.Amount)})).ToList();

lstAmountsByYear.Items.Add(AmountsByYear);
```

and:

```
var AmountsByYear = cars
                    .GroupBy(i => i.Date.Year)
                    .Select(g => new
                    {Year = g.Key,
                     Total = g.Sum(i => i.Amount)}).ToList();

lstAmountsByYear.Items.Add(AmountsByYear);
```

Comment: have you tried : `lstAmountsByYear.DataSource = AmountsByYear` ?

Comment: Add method expects one item. You probably want AddRange or just set the items to the collection

Comment: Now, after you edit, it's utterly unclear which part of the question is still relevant. Also, I have no idea what you're asking. What's wrong with the query (or queries?) you show?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in this line:

```
lstAmountsByYear.Items.Add(AmountsByYear);
```

`Add` expects a single item, not a list. You add the list here which is then displayed with its type name.

If this collection has a `AddRange` method, you could do this:

```
lstAmountsByYear.Items.AddRange(AmountsByYear);
```

otherwise you'll need to add each item separatly:

```
foreach(var item in AmountsByYear)
    lstAmountsByYear.Items.Add(item);
```